# Failed to download selenium and/or chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to install `selenium-standalone` using `npm install`, it was working fine in the past nad now I gets:

```
selenium-standalone installation starting
----------

---
selenium install:
from: https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.12/selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar
to: /root/circleci-dashboard/public/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.12.0-server.jar
---
chrome install:
from: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/chromedriver_linux64.zip
to: /root/circleci-dashboard/public/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.43-x64-chromedriver
---
firefox install:
from: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz
to: /root/circleci-dashboard/public/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/geckodriver/0.23.0-x64-geckodriver
Failed to download selenium and/or chromedriver: Error: Could not download https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.23.0/geckodriver-v0.23.0-linux64.tar.gz
    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/circleci-dashboard/public/node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/install.js:373:21)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/root/circleci-dashboard/public/node_modules/request/request.js:1066:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
selenium-standalone will attempt to re-download next time it is run.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: Note that it is failing on the geckodriver step, which is downloading a tar.gz. The chromedriver download right before it works fine, and that is a zip file. First, I'd put that url in your browser and verify that it downloads the file instantly when you navigate to it. Then, see what happens when you download other selenium dependencies individually without touching the geckodriver. There may be some setting preventing tar.gz files from streaming on your machine. Although I don't know what setting might cause that.